# how to open chm file using hyperlink

Tags: html, chm

I am developing a web application in which I implemented the help.chm file.

**My question is:**

How to open the chm help file by using a hyperlink in my web application without a download dialog box?

Comment: What browser are you testing in? Some browsers don't have chm support so they are going to prompt a download if they can't handle the mime type.

Answer (score 2):

You can't and you shouldn't. A chm is a [file archive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) that requires a separate viewer, it isn't rendered directly inside the browser.

There are also security considerations with these files, so with certain versions of Windows you cannot open them from a remote (including network) location - they must be opened from the local machine (IIRC this is on WinXP SP2+, Vista and Win 7).

Comment: You must manually unlock them in the files' properties even, when you save them on NTFS. Note that on FAT there afaik is no problem, since the feature is dependant on NTFS

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what is, in fact, a [`CHM`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Compiled_HTML_Help) file ? It's a set of html files compiled in a big archive. So, the simplest solution to open those files without showing the "download dialog", is to **not** package your html files as chm, but to left them on your web site, and make classical static links to them.